# Playing and Manipulating MIDI in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, midi, web-midi

I need to be able to play MIDI files in a React app and also manipulate certain things like tempo, channels, instruments, transposition, etc.

(Changing the tempo and activating/deactivating certain channels are probably the only hard requirement here.)

I'm working with Lilypond files to enter data and generate MIDI, since it seems you can get that into your browser in such a way that is possible to manipulate. I mention this because it means I have full control over the MIDI that's generated.

I've come across project like [MIDI.js](https://github.com/mudcube/MIDI.js/) and [WebMidi](https://github.com/cotejp/webmidi) which seem to offer something, but I am lacking a practical example to see how I might use anything out there in a React native kind of way.

Can I get my own MIDI files into a React app in such a way that they can be played and manipulated?

Answer (score 0):

Look to https://www.npmjs.com/package/midi-sounds-react

Full control for tracks, volume etc.
You need some other library to read events from MIDI file.